# Can I programmatically test a property with a StringLengthAttribute to check if it is valid?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Given that I have:

```
[StringLength(10)]
public string Bibble {get; set;}
```

Can I individually check to see if Bibble is valid?

I considered:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(MyBibbleObject).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    foreach (object attr in attrs)
    {
        StringLengthAttribute stringLengthAttribute = attr as StringLengthAttribute;
        if (stringLengthAttribute != null)
        {
            string propName = prop.Name;

// Could be IsValid?
            stringLengthAttribute.IsValid()


        }
    }
}
```

But the IsValid method requires an object, which I wasn't expecting. I'm wondering if there's a better way to establish if it's valid or not. I have to do it on a per-property basis.

Comment: Correct, you pass in the value you want to test.

Comment: In your current context, you can't access to ModelState ?

Comment: I was concerned that a) it requires a value, and b) whether or not it will be able to work on Arrays and various datatypes when it doesn't have access to the metadata of the property itself as a normal attribute would

Comment: This isn't an asp.net project so none of the asp.net model stuff applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in `Validator` class for that. Its usage is a bit vague, but still:

```
// instance is your MyBibbleObject object 
var ctx = new ValidationContext(instance);
// property to validate
ctx.MemberName = "Bibble";
// this will store results of validation. If empty - all fine
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
// pass value to validate (it won't take it from your object)
Validator.TryValidateProperty(instance.Bibble, ctx, results);
```